# Velocity and Accelaration in the z and w planes

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem

A particle $P$ moves along the line $x+y=2$ in the $z$-plane with a uniform speed of $3\sqrt 2$ feet per second from the point $z=-5+7i$ to $z=10-8i$. If $w=2z^2-3$ and $P'$ is the image of $P$ in the $w$-plane, find the magnitudes of

- a. the velocity and
- b. the acceleration of $P'$ after 3 seconds.

Comment: You can use the chain rule:  $\frac {dw}{dt}=\frac {dw}{dz}\cdot \frac {dz}{dt}$

Comment: Thanks but I do not have a formula involving t

Comment: When it says moves with a uniform speed, you should parameterize $z$ in terms of $t$.  So $z(t=0)=-5+7i$.  The speed you are given tells you the time the particle reaches $10-8i$  Now you have $\frac {dz}{dt}$

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution Image]

You need to write the equation of $x$ and $y$ in parametric form as you can see in the image. This might not be the best solution, the truth being, I am not so bright mathematician.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1843018)

Comment: @user264745 It's not a link-type answer. That's (was) an image uploaded.

Comment: It's better to try to write that answer here in mathjax format. It's quite easy to learn too.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sorry Guy's I am a newbie, so didn't have much idea. Thanks for your suggestions, will take care of the same next time around.